# Why i need to use return keyword in this function so the promise work correctly?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise

**Code:**

**script1.js:**

```
function getPeople(fetch) {
  fetch('some API').then(res => res.json()).then(data => {
     return {
       count: data.count,
       results: data.results
     }

  })
}

module.exports = getPeople;
```

**script2:**

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const getPeople = require('./script1');

getPeople(fetch).then(data => console.log(data) //TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
```

This error is resolved when add `return` keyword in `getPeople` function like this:

```
function getPeople(fetch) {
  return fetch('some API').then(res => res.json()).then(data => {
     return {
       count: data.count,
       results: data.results
     }

  })
}
```

I wonder why i need this `return` keyword before `fetch()` while i already use it to return  data:

```
 return {
       count: data.count,
       results: data.results
     }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't return the promise from your function that `fetch()` creates, then your function is just returning `undefined` and NOTHING is communicated back to the caller.  You have to return the promise.

The return of your data is a return to the `.then()` callback.  That's not a return from your function.  That return is also needed because that sets the resolved value of the parent promise, but that just returns back from the callback into the promise infrastructure and is not a return from your function itself.  To return from the function itself, you need a `return` that isn't nested inside some other function.

Comment: You mean i need to return another promise to then, i need to return a promise expression ??

Comment: @SaherElgendy - No, please read what I just added to my answer.  Your second implementation of `getPeople()` is the correct way to do it.  In your first implementation, there is no `return` statement at all for `getPeople()`, only one for the promise callback so nothing is returned from `getPeople()`.

Comment: I am confused now, so i need that return to return from the function itself or return something to promise infrastructure??

Comment: @SaherElgendy - The "return" statement inside "then" in your case doesn't actually do anything. You can remove the last "then". You are taking "count" and putting it into "count" which is redundant. Using return inside the callback inside "then" is used to format the output. Your second example is good, you can remove the "then" with the return. Basically, `return fetch(...).then(res => res.json())` is fine and all you need.

Comment: @LeonardoG - You can't really tell if the inner return does anything or not.  The OP may be wanting to resolve with only two properties of many or it could be redundant.  Anyway, in the context of this discussion it isn't hurting anything.  But, not having a return value at all from `getPeople()` is the main issue here.

Comment: @jfriend00 true, but I'd wager OP didn't really understand what the inner return does since they asked this question. If the response contains only "count" and "results", then it's redundant. Basically, the inner return is here just to format the data.

Comment: @SaherElgendy - You need the `return` in `return fetch()...` so that your `getPeople()` function returns the promise.   Without that return, the `getPeople()` function is not returning anything.

Comment: @jfriend00 ok, i know why i am wrong now, thank you